# create hasMany or one to many relationship from a pivot table - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-normalization

I have 3 Tables:

**Companies**

**Products**

**Images**

Now, **Companies** and **Products** are **Many to Many** relationship.

Meaning, 1 company can have many products and a product can belong to multiple companies. So, I have a pivot table called **companies_products** with pivot or additional columns such as: price, discount, status, etc...

Note: Products table represents only common-data, that is, it does not have price, status, etc... product is only complete with pivot cols because that is how it makes a product unique to each company.

Everything is fine until here. Now because pivot table represents a unique product cols for each company. I also want to attach product-images table to this pivot table. Which means, **my structure would be each pivot row hasMany product_images.**

But in Laravel I guess pivot tables does not have a model, it is not encouraged to do so. Then how to achieve has-Many with pivot table?

Or any better solution to structure my tables or data?

In summary,

I have 1 companies table and 1 products table (unique).

companies create final product by adding extra data and images(array). I can handle extra data which goes as a pivot cols but not images (which in this case is array of images. I cant have 1 to many directly at products table level because each company adds a product with extra data to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a model for a pivot table. It's covered in the [Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) of the docs. To do this, the class of your model should extend:

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`

instead of

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.